# React useContext: Dispatch is never propagating up to parent components, despite being set to non-null value

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I'm attempting to utilize the React [context + reducer](https://react.dev/learn/scaling-up-with-reducer-and-context) state management strategy, but `const dispatch = useContext(DispatchContext);` in my `App` component is never updating beyond `null`, even though it is being set in my `ContextProvider` component.  I'm guessing it has something to do with my hooks not being configured correctly, but I'm not sure how?

Anyway, here is the code below and a link to a Sandbox that showcases the issue.  I'd expect, given the code, that the resulting printed value should be "inittest" rather than just "init".  I've added `console.logs` that are hopefully useful in demonstrating the issue.

```
import { Dispatch, createContext, useContext, useEffect, useReducer, useState } from 'react';

interface ContextValue {
  test: string
}

export type TestState = ContextValue;
const initialState: TestState = {
  test: 'init',
};

interface Action {
  type: string;
  payload?: any;
}

const ValueContext = createContext<TestState>(initialState);
const DispatchContext = createContext<Dispatch<Action> | null>(null);

interface Props {
  children: React.ReactNode;
}


class ContextActions {
  public dispatch: Dispatch<Action>;

  constructor(dispatch: Dispatch<Action>) {
    this.dispatch = dispatch;
  }

  append(value: string) {
    return this.dispatch({
      type: 'append',
      payload: value,
    });
  }
}

function reducer(state: TestState, action: Action): TestState {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'append': {
      return {
        ...state,
        test : state.test + action.payload,
      };
    }
    default: {
      throw new Error(`Unhandled action type: ${action.type}`);
    }
  }
}

export const ContextProvider: React.FunctionComponent<Props> = ({
  children,
}) => {
  const [value, dispatch] = useReducer(reducer, initialState);
  console.log('ContextProvider', value, 'dispatch set: ' + !!dispatch);
  return (
    <ValueContext.Provider value={value}>
      <DispatchContext.Provider value={dispatch}>
        {children}
      </DispatchContext.Provider>
    </ValueContext.Provider>
  );
}

export function useTest(): [
  TestState,
  ContextActions | null,
] {
  const dispatch = useContext(DispatchContext);
  const [ actions, setActions ] = useState<ContextActions | null>(null);
  useEffect(() => {
    if (dispatch) {
      console.log('useTest.useEffect if(dispatch)');
      if (!actions) {
        console.log('useTest.useEffect if(dispatch) && if(!actions)');
        setActions(new ContextActions(dispatch));
      } else {
        console.log('useTest.useEffect if(dispatch) && (action already set)');
        actions.dispatch = dispatch;
      }
    } else {
      console.log('useTest.useEffect (no dispatch)');
    }
  }, [dispatch, actions]);
  return [
    useContext(ValueContext),
    actions,
  ];
}

export default function App() {
  const [value, actions] = useTest();

  useEffect(() => {
    if (actions) {
      console.log('TestPage.useEffect if(actions)', actions);
      actions.append('test');
    } else {
      console.log('TestPage.useEffect (no actions)');
    }
  }, [actions]);

  return (
    <ContextProvider>
      <div>{value.test}</div>
    </ContextProvider>
  );
}
```

[image: Edit React Typescript (forked)]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem you have is that you try to use useContext hook in the same component that defines context provider. This will not work in React. The Context provider and useContext hooks need to be in two different components:

try something like this:

```js
function Main() {
  const [value, actions] = useTest();

  useEffect(() => {
    if (actions) {
      console.log('TestPage.useEffect if(actions)', actions);
      actions.append('test');
    } else {
      console.log('TestPage.useEffect (no actions)');
    }
  }, [actions]);

  return <div>{value.test}</div>;
}


export default function App() {
  return (
    <ContextProvider>
      <Main />
    </ContextProvider>
  );
}
```

This is the limitation of the Context API in React.

Comment: Ah, perfect, thank you!  Now that I understand the issue, I can see my question is a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/58152818/6090140 so I marked it as such.